# Why "loading external scripts" errors suddenly?

Tags: discussion

I'm using Chrome and it is configured to block loading of external scripts... So why am I suddenly getting notifications of "external scripts" being blocked and indicating "Stack OverFlow" requires the loading of external scripts?

I can understand using a CDN for scripts, but in today's world isn't that like opening the pot to a can of worms?

Comment: What is blocking from the [What else do I need](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100) list?